# Graphics in games rendering weirdly

Tags: graphics

Any ideas as to what would cause the graphics of some 3d models in some games render weirdly like these?

This only started happening last week. I've made sure graphics card drivers are all up to date but I can't think of what else could be causing this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Appears as though it's failing to render some of the polygons.  If you turn down one or more of the graphics settings (world detail, screen resolution, etc) does the problem go away?  Don't know why it would randomly start doing that, but it's a good place to start looking.

Comment: This reminds me of single sided polygons that are rendered facing the wrong direction. When a polygon is rendered, it can have two sides or one. One-sided polygons are faster to render and objects are usually created this way, but they could face the wrong way. Which would look exactly like the above pix. Except somebody would have noticed long long before now  :) But there are other techniques in gaming (rendering) that could cause this... backface culling/clipping/z-culling... you might to check for settings in your game mentioning this.

Comment: I would turn the game settings UP (high) to see if this fixes the issue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling

Comment: Actually now that you mention it I did turn some settings down a little while ago as it was lagging a little. ill try turning them back up

Comment: Nope still messed up :\

Comment: I have noticed the computer running really hot at the moment so I wonder if its the graphics card overheating